# Can I ask question that is to identify the name of thing? What tags I should use to post such question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question that I don't know what to tag with, because I want to know what it is. It sounds a bit vague; I will just post my question to make it clearer:

Title: What is name of equations that accept division by zero?

Body:

> They might not have a name; they just popped in my head, and I found out that they are useful in a way; I am interested in more information about them by knowing their name.
>
> An equation for example:
>
> $f(x) = nx$
>
> $f'(x) = (f(x+0)-f(x))/0 = (nx+0n-nx)/0 = (0n)/0 = n$
>
> More *hardcore* one:
>
> $f(x) = a^x$
>
> $f'(x) = (f(x+0)-f(x))/0 = (a^{x+0}-a^x)/0 = (a^x(a^0-1))/0 = (a^x(e^{\ln(a^0)}-1))/0 = (a^x(e^{0\ln(a)}-1))/0$
>
> Place $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + ... + x^k/!k$ in $f'(x)$.
>
> $f'(x) = (a^x(1 + 0\ln(a) + ... - 1))/0 = (a^x(0\ln(a) + ...))/0 = a^x(\ln(a) + (...)/0)$
>
> Discard values that are $0$ that we can't rescue them with that $/0$.
>
> $f'(x) = a^x(\ln(a)) = a^x\ln(a) $
>
> This is not limit, but normal mathematics that don't panic in front of a $/0$.

Tags: [nonstandard-analysis] [limits] [infinitesimals] Those are the tags that gave me the impression from the comments that I need to use.

Is it acceptable in the main site? Do I need to choose different SE site? If it's acceptable, then what are the tags that is required to submit such question?

Comment: The reason we have formalized **limits** is for that exact purpose (derivatives).  Also, there are no non-negative numbers that are less than zero.  The problem with what you've suggested is that it does not lead to well-defined results.  I would vote to close the proposed question as "unclear as to what you are asking."

Comment: I would suggest reading about [non-standard analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis) and then asking a focused question. That said, +1 to *this* question, for asking on meta first.

Comment: I'd upvote this were it on main, since I think it could be begetting of a good answer and I think it's a really really common train of thought that plenty of people would benefit from an answer of (and an answer better than "no, you can't divide by zero"). That said, I think a stronger question would be to ask about how such things are *formalized* - since that gives answers a pretty clear purpose. (In any case, whatever it is that you're really trying to ask with this question is on-topic if you ask it well)

Comment: @anorton Thanks for your feedback; I improved that part, is it any better now? I don't understand the `well-define result` part. If I will add that those equations made to work around the division by zero, then will it work?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Thanks; it helped me find some tags.

Comment: @Meelo Looks like it will be more interesting like that while getting the name too; thanks I will edit later.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035282/why-those-division-by-zero-formalized posted the question, thanks everyone. By the way I posted in this account by accident, this is not mine. (The other one in the question is mine)

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the suitability of the question proposed above:

In general it is okay to ask about names of things and identifying objects. Please tag them with [notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) and/or [terminology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) as appropriate.